# Compose expansions in Maclaurin evaluation?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

My friend and I have a discussion about the Maclaurin evaluation up to degree 9 on this function:

$$f(x) = \sin(\arctan(x^2))$$

We have the hint (from another post) that we can compose the expansions:

$$\arctan x = x -\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^{\frac92})$$

$$\arctan x^2 =x^2 -\frac{x^6}{3}+o(x^9)$$

$$\sin t = t -\frac{t^3}{6}+o(t^3)$$

Thus for $t= \arctan x^2 =x^2 -\frac{x^6}{3}+o(x^9)$

$$\sin (\arctan x^2) = x^2 -\frac{x^6}{3}-\frac16\left(x^2 -\frac{x^6}{3}\right)^3+o(x^9)=\\=x^2 -\frac{x^6}{3}-\frac{x^6}{6}+o(x^9)=x^2 -\frac{x^6}{2}+o(x^9)$$

However, I do wonder why or how to explain this when the standard form for $sin(x)$ is:

$$\sin(x) = x - {\frac{x^3}{3!}} + {\frac{x^5}{5!}} - {\frac{x^7}{7!}}+\cdots$$

Why does degree $5$ and $7$ vanish even though we search for up to degree 9? Is it because they are odd? And the same question applies for $\arctan(x)$ and $\arctan(x^2)$.

Comment: May be, the problem would have been different if we notice that $\sin(\arctan(x^2))=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}$. Then, using the binomial theorem, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know well this expansion, It was a my answer.

Note thet degree 5 and 7 vanish because the minimum degree in $\arctan x^2$ expansion is n=2 thus $(x^2)^5$ and $(x^2)^7$ are both greater than $x^9$ and can be neglected.

Remember that: $$\forall n>9 \quad x^{n}+o(x^9)=o(x^9)$$

Therefore, in order to have a final order n=9, in this case we only need to consider $\sin t$ expansion at order n=3.

In any case if you have some doubt on this, you can consider a full expansion with all the terms and then simplify neglecting the orders $>9$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sin\bigl(\arctan(x^2)\bigr)$ is an even function. Therefore, its Maclaurin series (around $0$) cannot have terms with odd exponents (or, to put it better, the coefficients of these terms must be $0$).

Comment: Can you please explain this further? @José Carlos Santos How can I show that it is an even function? And what theorem or rule explains it?

Comment: @micor It is an even function because $\sin\bigl(\arctan((-x)^2)\bigr)=\sin\bigl(\arctan(x^2)\bigr)$ (since $(-x)^2=x^2$).

Comment: @micor Were you asking why is it that the Maclaurin series at $0$ of an even function cannot have terms with odd exponents?

Comment: Thank you. How to explain the $\frac {x^3}{3!} then? It is also an odd exponent but still not terminated?

Comment: @micor The $\frac{x^3}{3!}$ term appears in the Maclaurin series of the sine function, which is an odd function, not an even one.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the question was why we do not consider the terms $\geq 5$ for $\sin t$ expansion when we plug in $\arctan x^2$ expansion, it is not a matter of odd/even function

Comment: @gimusi I understand that now. Thank you. I got confused by the fact that the OP wrote “Why does degree 5 and 7 vanish”, instead of asking why aren't they used.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Do not worry, I was facilitated in understanding the OP because the original answer was mine!